# Apache NiFi 1.3: How would I approach passing sets of vin #s through the htsa.dot.gov API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, apache-nifi

Fellow Techies--
I am trying to determine the best way to move several thousand VIN#'s per hour through https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/ to parse out the array of features associated with each. I have two method choices, a DecodeVINValuesBatch and DecodeVIN. The batch version allows an array, the DecodeVIN is a single reference. In the .NET/C# or  JBOSS + DBMS environments, I know that I would approach the problem by first calling the DecodeVINValuesBatch, then while processing through, capture each of the value Ids in the vPIC collection while writing out the datasets. I don't anticipate set theory being any different in NiFi--but I am unfamiliar with this tool--and have not come across any examples representative of solving for processing multiple sets over a continuous input stream.  My thoughts on this are that I would begin with the InvokeHTTP processor which captures the VIN#'s + multiple other pieces of data, while splitting the multiple portions of the data into different processors. One of those processors would need to isolate the VIN# to another InvokeHTTP processor to make the external call to NHTSA. On the one hand, it appears that in this context, the single DecodeVIN would be the better choice. On the other hand, I am wondering how best to manage this data. Should I be thinking about missed data, duplicates, etc. -- therefore prepared to process in sets? I'm looking for guidance and best practices for production quality NiFi implmentations. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't resolve the API you linked to, but here is a general pattern for performing this type of behavior.

You are correct that an `InvokeHTTP` processor is the best candidate for retrieving data from a remote HTTP endpoint. The resulting flowfile content will contain the response from the HTTP call, which for example's sake let's say is in JSON format. If my understanding of your description of the available API methods is correct, you have two options:

1. `DecodeVIN` accepts a single VIN value and returns some dataset for the particular VIN
2. `DecodeVINValuesBatch` accepts an array of VIN values and returns an array of datasets corresponding to the provided VINs

I would almost certainly recommend the second option if you are attempting to achieve throughput of "several thousand" VINs per hour. It will drastically reduce network overhead (by orders of magnitude) and reduce extraneous processing to split records.

In order to transform the incoming format of the data to an acceptable argument for that batch method, you should examine the `ConvertRecord` processor and the associated `RecordReader` and `RecordSetWriter` controller service families. This feature was introduced in Apache NiFi 1.2.0 (and enhanced in 1.3.0) and allows for arbitrary streams of data to be converted, queried, and enriched independently of their format. Bryan Bende has written a good [introductory guide to using the components](http://bryanbende.com/development/2017/06/20/apache-nifi-records-and-schema-registries), Mark Payne has written extensively on the [record conversion process](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi) and [realtime querying](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/real-time-sql-on-event),  and the [RecordPath Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html) is a comprehensive reference resource.

Once the flowfile content has been translated to the proper form for the batch API, you could use `InvokeHTTP` to perform the lookup operation, and handle the outgoing flowfile which will contain the HTTP response, or you could use the new `LookupRecord` processor with a `LookupService` controller service, including `ScriptedLookupService` which allows you to write arbitrary Python/Groovy/Ruby code to perform the lookup operation (i.e. HTTP call to enrich a record).

You may also be interested in `PartitionRecord`, which allows grouping "like" records based on some RecordPath expression (i.e. filtering bad data records, irrelevant records, etc.). Finally, for completeness, there are also the `QueryRecord`, `SplitRecord`, and `UpdateRecord` processors which you may be interested in.

Prior to 1.2.0, individual conversion processors like `ConvertCSVToJSON` and `SplitText` would likely have been necessary, but this new paradigm should fit your use case well.

Comment: Andy, thanks so much for your thorough response. I really appreciate it. I will research the blogs/examples/processor families you've referenced. For the sake of consistency, I will correct the url in the original post.